# Python legend attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Why am I getting an error here that relates to the plt.plot label?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
barplt = plt.bar(bins,frq,align='center',label='Dgr')
normplt = plt.plot(bins_n,frq_n,'--r', label='Norm');
ax.set_xlim([min(bins)-1, max(bins)+1])
ax.set_ylim([0, max(frq)])
plt.xlabel('Dgr')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
plt.legend(handles=[barplt,normplt])
```

This is the error that I get:
*'list' object has no attribute 'get_label'*

Comment: You question would have been improved by posting the *full traceback*.  That would have pinpointed the line that caused the issue and helped people answer the question.  It also would have helped you solve your own issue.  Had your question been written more carefully, it may have received an upvote.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because `plt.plot` can plot more than one line at once, it returns a list of `line2D` objects, even if you only plot one line (i.e. in your case, a list of length 1). When you grab its handle for the legend, you want to only use the first item of this list (the actual `line2D` object).

There are (at least) two ways you can resolve this:

1) add a comma after `normplt` when you call `plt.plot`, to only store the first item from the list in `normplt`

```
barplt = plt.bar(bins,frq,width,align='center',label='Dgr')
normplt, = plt.plot(bins_n,frq_n,'--r', label='Norm')   # note the comma after normplt

print normplt
# Line2D(Norm)    <-- This is the line2D object, not a list, so we can use it in legend
...
plt.legend(handles=[barplt,normplt])
```

2) Use only the first item in the list when you call `plt.legend` (`normplt[0]`):

```
barplt = plt.bar(bins,frq,width,align='center',label='Dgr')
normplt = plt.plot(bins_n,frq_n,'--r', label='Norm')

print normplt
# [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x112076710>]  
# Note, this is a list containing the Line2D object. We just want the object, 
# so we can use normplt[0] in legend
...
plt.legend(handles=[barplt,normplt[0]])
```

Answer (score 6):

In new **matplotlib version** (**3.1.0**) was added [new method](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/users/whats_new.html#legend-for-scatter)
for creating legends for scatter plots.

> Now, PathCollection provides a method legend_elements() to obtain the handles and labels for a scatter plot in an automated way. This makes creating a legend for a scatter plot as easy as

So, you can also use [automated legend creation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automatedlegendcreation):

```py
N = 45
x, y = np.random.rand(2, N)
c = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=N)
s = np.random.randint(10, 220, size=N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=s)

# produce a legend with the unique colors from the scatter
legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), loc="lower left", title="Classes")
ax.add_artist(legend1)

# produce a legend with a cross section of sizes from the scatter
handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes", alpha=0.6)
legend2 = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc="upper right", title="Sizes")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting us know it was just added -- I came here wondering why I was getting `'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'legend_elements'` in an older version.