# Adding legend to scatterplot when color is encoded

Tags: python, legend, scatter-plot, pca

[image]

I can't add legend to my scatterplot.
The problem that color is encoded by variable y which takes two values 0 or 1.
X comes from PCA method, I try to plot 2 principal components with different colors corresponding to different y.
I get error mesage "No handles with labels found to put in legend."

Tried different tutorial, but still cofused.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.scatter(x_reduced[:,0], x_reduced[:,1],c=y, alpha=0.5)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you provide data examples? (x_reduced, y)

Comment: If you're using a newer version of Matplotlib (>=3.1), this answer will help: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236062/4531017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a newer version of Matplotlib (>=3.1), then you can add legends to a scatterplot following this answer: [Scatterplot legends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236062/4531017)

Otherwise, a workaround is to do two separate calls to `plt.scatter`

```
# one scatter for y == 0
plt.scatter(x_reduced[y==0,0], x_reduced[y==0,1], alpha=0.5, label = "group1")
# another scatter for y == 1
plt.scatter(x_reduced[y==1,0], x_reduced[y==1,1], alpha=0.5, label = "group2")

# create legend for both
plt.legend()
```