# PathCollection' object has no attribute legend_elements''

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I know this exact question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329269/python-legend-attribute-error), however the current solution does nothing for me. I can't seem to generate a legend that has a different color for each label. I have tried the current documentation on [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automatedlegendcreation) to no avail. I keep getting the error that my `PathCollection object has no attribute legend_elements`

EDIT: Also, I want my legend to be just the `Years`, unique years for the plot not how it is right now with is that each data point is mapped to my legend.
Here's what I have

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.pyplot import legend
import os

%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

path = None
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)

# Indexes to be removed
early_demo_dividend = 13
high_income = 24
lower_middle_income = 40
north_america = 46
members = 50
post_demo = 56
_removals = [early_demo_dividend, high_income, lower_middle_income, north_america, members, post_demo]

#Read in data
df = pd.read_csv(path)

#Get the rows we want
df = df.loc[df['1960'] > 1]
df = df.drop(columns=["Code", "Type", "Indicator Name"])

#Remove the odd rows
for i in _removals:
    df = df.drop(df.index[i])

#Format the dataframe
df = df.melt('Name', var_name='Year', value_name='Budget')

#Plot setup
plt.figure().set_size_inches(16,6)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.grid(True)

#Plot labels
plt.title('Military Spending of Countries')
plt.xlabel('Countries')
plt.ylabel('Budget in Billions')

#Plot data
new_year = df['Year'].astype(int)
scatter = plt.scatter(df['Name'], df['Budget'], c=(new_year / 10000) , label=new_year)

#Legend setup produce a legend with the unique colors from the scatter
legend1 = plt.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(),
                    loc="lower left", title="Years")
plt.add_artist(legend1)

plt.show()
```

Heres my plot 
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I also encountered this problem.

Try to upgrade your `matplotlib` with `pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib`

```
    Uninstalling matplotlib-3.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-3.0.3
Successfully installed matplotlib-3.1.2
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Despite the fact that my answer may not be relevant to the current question, I decided to leave it to describe my case - it might be useful to someone else:

When using matplotlib functions such as `scatter` or `plot`, incorrectly specify the name of some additional arguments, you can get the same error.
Example:

```
x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(10))
plt.scatter(x, y, labels='RESULT')
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'labels'

As it said in error message (but it is not obvious to an inattentive developer :) ):
the problem that I use `labels` instead of `label`